# Mix Any() and First() in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

First Im a noob in LINQ !
Then, the thing is that I have a Collection that :

1. either does not contain my ID (string)
2. or contains it ONLY once

I wanted to use Where but I don't like the `if` instructions that I have to do... so here is my code :

```
if (MyCollection.Any(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName))
{
    var tmp = MyCollection.First(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName);
}
```

This works but I really feel like this is not the way I should do it with LINQ...
Any suggestion ?

Comment: you should check `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Why don't you use FirstOrDefault(), and after the query you check if your result is null or it contains your data?

Comment: didnt know this Method :( I prefer SingleOrDefault anyway !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Non-Unique Entity Answer** (with exception throwing on multiple instances)

Use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx). This will return the unique item if it exists, null if it doesn't exist or it will throw and exception if there is more than one.

```
var tmp = MyCollection.SingleOrDefault(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName);
```

**Unique Property Answer** (there will never be multiple instances)

If your system is set up so that `BaseName` is a unique entity, user `FirstOrDefault`, this won't throw an exception if there are multiple as it will stop at the first instance, but the system will be designed so there will never be the same instance, so it would be acceptable (and time reducing).

```
var tmp = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName);
```

Comment: This is really nice ! The exception handling is very nice :)

Comment: It's nice in a way that if there is ever a match then it will throw an exception, but if your system is setup that it is not possible for a duplicate then the exception will never be required then go with FirstOrDefault (only if it's a primary key or has set validation upon insertion).

Answer (score 12):

As ThePower says, you should use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) or perhaps [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx). If there's genuinely only one such entry, they'll do the same thing, but `FirstOrDefault` may well be faster if you're using LINQ to Objects - `SingleOrDefault` would have to scan through the complete sequence to check that there aren't any other matches.

If there are multiple matches, `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception; `FirstOrDefault` will just return the first match.

So you might use:

```
var result = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName);
if (result != null)
{
    // Use it
}
```

Note that this may be awkward if your sequence element type is a value type, as you may not be able to distinguish between the default value for the element type due to there being no matches, and a "real" value. It looks like that's unlikely to be a problem in this case, but it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: Good point Jon. It's tricky to see whether it was a primary key or uniquely defined element, a great addition nevertheless.

Answer (score 5):

```
var tmp = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName));
```

Here tmp will be null if you don't have such record.

Comment: What if it is a `struct` type though?

Answer (score 2):

you may use,

```
FirstOrDefault()
```

or

```
SingleOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `FirstOrDefault(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName);`

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`Any` returns `bool` to indicates if such items exists, `First` returns the record from your collection. So in any case you will have object from collection and your condition result. You can use `FirstOrDefault` and then check for `null` your returned value.

```
var tmp = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName);
if (tmp != null) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tmp = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(rm => rm.BaseName == rbName);
if (tmp != null)
{
    // Do something
}
```